# how to replace 'selected text' => 'decorated text' in react / textarea? i can't get exact location(index) of 'selected text'

Tags: reactjs, range, selection, text-decorations

i'm trying to build some text editor with react

i'm not native in english, so sorry about below question

---

what i want to do is like this below

[(it's 'notion' page gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jhRq.gif)

- if user drag text with mouse(or with keyboard) to set a block in some texts,
- popup menu(to edit 'seleted texts') show

i'm stuck at first one.

i can get whole text and selected text

- `let wholeText = whole.anchorNode.childNodes[0].defaultValue;`
- `let selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();`

but i can't get 'exact location' of `selectedText` in `wholeText`

---

here's my code (react, styled-component)

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import autosize from 'autosize';

export default function TextBox({ id, index, content, handleContentInput }) {
  const [currentContent, setCurrentContent] = useState(content);
  const [areaHeight, setAreaHeight] = useState(25);

  useEffect(() => {
    autosize(document.querySelector(`.TextBoxWrap_${id}`));
  }, [currentContent]);

  return (
    <TextBoxContainer
      className={`TextBoxContainer_${id}`}
      areaHeight={areaHeight}
      onClick={() => {
        document.querySelector(`.TextBoxContainer_${id}`).focus();
      }}
    >
      <TextBoxWrap
        className={`TextBoxWrap_${id}`}
        areaHeight={areaHeight}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setCurrentContent(event.target.value);
        }}
        onBlur={() => handleContentInput(id, index, currentContent)}
        onKeyUp={() => {
          let newHeight = document.querySelector(`.TextBoxWrap_${id}`)
            .clientHeight;
          setAreaHeight(newHeight);
        }}
        onMouseUp={() => {
          let whole = window.getSelection();
          if (!whole) return;

          let range = whole.getRangeAt(0);

          console.log({ whole, range });

          let wholeText = whole.anchorNode.childNodes[0].defaultValue;

          let selectedText = whole.toString();

          console.log({ wholeText, selectedText });

          let start = range.startOffset; // Start position
          let end = range.endOffset; // End position

          console.log({ start, end });
        }}
        value={currentContent}
      ></TextBoxWrap>
    </TextBoxContainer>
  );
}

const TextBoxContainer = styled.div`
  max-width: 890px;
  width: 100%;
  height: ${(props) => `${props.areaHeight}px`};

  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
`;

const TextBoxWrap = styled.textarea`
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  box-sizing: 'border-box';
  border: none;
  outline: none;

  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;

  /* padding: 2x; */
  box-shadow: none;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden; // Removes scrollbar
  resize: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  /* line-height: 1.5em; */
  /* font-family: Georgia, 'Malgun Gothic', serif; */
`;
```

inside of `onMouseUp`, it works like this

- console.log({ wholeText, selectedText }); : works fine
- console.log({ start, end }); : always 0, 0

`wholeText.indexOf(selectedText)` was my option, but `indexOf()` gives me just 'first' index matches,

so, even if i want "aaaaaa'a'aa" but indexOf will give me '0' (=> "'a'aaaaaaaaaa")

---

what i was thinking,

- get the 'exact index(location)', and cut `wholeText` with it
- decorate `selectedText` with popup box (return html element? like <span style{{color: 'red'}}>${selectedText}
- then, combine these three items (wholeText_front, decorated_selectedText, wholeText_back)
- and, to place popup menu div right above seleted texts

which means, i need 'selected one's location

---

how can i do this? plz give me advice

thank you!

---

posts i read before post this question

- [How to find index of selected text in getSelection() using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574059/how-to-find-index-of-selected-text-in-getselection-using-javascript)
- [How to get the start and end points of selection in text area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053542/how-to-get-the-start-and-end-points-of-selection-in-text-area)
- [replace selected text in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997659/replace-selected-text-in-contenteditable-div)
- [Replacing selected text - HTML / JavaScript](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/897645/Replacing-selected-text-HTML-JavaScript)
- [Select Text & highlight selection or get selection value (React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184603/select-text-highlight-selection-or-get-selection-value-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i might have some solution for my question, so post this answer myself

---

in this question([How to get the start and end points of selection in text area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053542/how-to-get-the-start-and-end-points-of-selection-in-text-area)), 'Tim Down' answered with `getInputSelection` function.

`getInputSelection` needs `el` as parameter, and i thought this is some kind of 'html element'

so, from this question([get id of focused element using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991990/get-id-of-focused-element-using-javascript/9992103)
), i got a hint : `document.activeElement`

and, i tried `getInputSelection(document.activeElement)` and got an object like `{ start: (number), end: (number) }`